# Alternative to Gnote when using Unity

Tags: 11.10, unity, software-recommendation, gnote

I like the Gnote is a great application but unfortunately has no app icon, I would like to know if there is any alternative to Gnote working in the systray of Unity.

Note: Tomboy is not an option

Comment: Why is not Tomboy an option?

Comment: I'm cleaning my ubuntu from mono apps... The next distro is clean of mono apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Zim](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zim) [image: Install zim]. It's more of a wiki type application, but it's great for taking notes, and will work with Unity's appindicators.

Comment: Looks nice, I installed the last version, I like that work with Unity's appindicators but is very slow when I click on systray icon to create a new note (fast notes) :(

Comment: @JoZ3 that's odd. Zim is normally very quick.

Comment: +1, good suggestion Roland, the Latex feature in this application is superb. quite speedy on my 10.1 Ubuntu, do not know what JoZ3's problem is.

Comment: Yes is very quick when I open normally but when I click on the systray icon is very slow to response

Comment: Solved, now Zim opens quickly, in preferences, extensions, I checked the first option in the configuration from systray icon extension

Answer (score -1):

You can use use Gnote and enable its systray icon. Here's how you do it, run this in the terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'gnote']"
```

In the future, any other app you want to have a systray icon for in Unity, run the same command, just add your app onto the end like so:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'gnote', 'YOUR_APPLICATION']"
```

Every app in there will be whitelisted to show its systray icon. You can get the current whitelist entries with the following command:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
```

Comment: Thanks I know this, the problems is that Gnote dont have system icon, only have systray icon like a panel addon in gnome 2